# What is the lowest latency communication method between a computer and a microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, stm32

I have a project in which I need to have the lowest latency possible (in the 1-100 microseconds range at best) for a communication between a computer (Windows + Linux + MacOSX) and a microcontroller (arduino or stm32 or anything).

I stress that not only it has to be fast, but with low latency (for example a fast communication to the moon will have a low latency).

For the moment the methods I have tried are serial over USB or HID packets over USB. I get results around a little less than a millisecond. My measurement method is a round trip communication, then divide by two. This is OK, but I would be much more happy to have something faster.

EDIT:
The question seems to be quite hard to answer. The best workaround I found is to synchronize clocks of the computer and microcontroler. Synchronization requires communication indeed. With the process below, `dt` is half a round trip, and `sync` is the difference between the clocks.

```
t = time()
write(ACK);
read(remotet)
dt = (time() - t) / 2
sync = time() - remotet - dt
```

Note that the imprecision of this synchronization is at most `dt`. The importance of the fastest communication channel stands, but I have an estimation of the precision.

Also note technicalities related to the difference of timestamp on different systems (us/ms based on epoch on Linux, ms/us since the MCU booted on Arduino).

Pay attention to the clock shift on Arduino. It is safer to synchronize often (every measure in my case).

Comment: How will you guarantee that "Windows + Linux + MacOSX" meets your latency requirement?

Comment: One way to accomplish this is to develop your own PCI card for the computer and connect it directly to the external memory interface for the MCU. For example FSMC on the stm32. Perhaps you also need to develop your own OS to meet your need, but this is perhaps not an option :)

Comment: @DKrueger this is part of waht I would like to measure. That's why I need something faster.

Comment: @staringlizard I saw there are FPGA cards. This would be useful. However I doubt I can use this method with a Mac. And ideally I would like to be able to do this with mobiles.

Comment: an old-fashioned parallel port would be faster than serial-over-usb, about 1/115000s. microphones should be pretty fast too, certainly faster than 1000Hz.

Comment: Parallel port is difficult to find on today's computers. Especially Mac. Microphones are fast, but what about latency? USB is much faster than 1KHz, but this seems not sufficient.

Comment: @Tom I think that you will have more luck if you say what you want to achieve... Because... Well, for microseconds delay I wouldn't trust a general purpose OS (win, linux, mac) because they are unpredictible. And by the way, a high speed communication to the moon could have a high bandwidth, but a its latency will be very high (the lowest possible with current physics is about 2.5 seconds)

Comment: @frarugi87 the example of the moon is exactly what I said. My objective is to measure latency of a system happening both on a computer/tablet (including software) and hardware parts connected by USB, measured with the microcontroller. The unpredictable latency of USB on regular OS is part of what I would like to measure. Thus I need to communicate between the computer/tablet and the microcontroller as fast as possible, and with the lowest latency possible. Ideally better than USB.

Comment: @Tom yes, but you said that it has a low latency, while the latency is quite high ;) anyway ok, now I understood what your problem is. You want to measure the time without the round trip method... In this case I think that you can try another approach: use a single board PC (e.g. a Raspberry PI, or something similar) with GPIOs. Then use their GPIO to detect the modification, and send the packet out with the USB. Your results can be poorer than state of the art PCs, because rPI USB is poor, but... well, still more results.

Comment: Just one more comment: check the schematic of the SBC if you want to use them. For instance if you use a common raspberry pi (1, 2, 3) you will also have latency introduced by the USB HUB (their CPU has only one USB and no ethernet, so f you have more ports or ethernet there is a hub). Better use a rPI zero, or an alternative without a HUB (I think that the Orange PIs and the Banana PIs do not have it). If you require windows, note that there is a win10 version called IOT that runs also on small computers (rPI3, bananaPI M64 - but beware, bPI-M64 has a HUB - but the OTG port is directly conn)

Comment: You're right, I meant high indeed. I also thought about the Raspberry Pi. I cannot use windows or MacOSX on it. However there is a variation of OS, which is a good point. The GPIO is exactly what I need, and I wish I had access to something like this with a regular computer. I regret the parallel port era indeed. I also considered audio. Somebody mentioned a microphone. However I know latency is an issue for audio applications. But even picky musicians are ok with around 10ms of latency. This is because it is the limit of temporal judgement of audition.

Comment: Even if a method that could communicate with the microcontroller in a microsecond existed, it wouldn't eliminate latency from the OS. There will always be some variable delay in getting such a request through the driver stack and to the hardware. So even when you get your final measurement you wouldn't know which part of the latency was from USB link and which part from the high-speed communication link.

Comment: Hoping by this point you understand that this is not possible nor practical.  The "computer" will vary extremely widely not only in the motherboards, etc, but the operating system, no two runs are expected to take the same amount of time etc.  Then you mention you didnt care whether it is an avr or stm, etc,  well assuming the computer wasnt a HUGE problem, the microcontroller AND ITS SOFTWARE, also make a big difference, plus everything in between.

Comment: If you had gpio on both ends that would help your measurement slightly, the parallel port in the old days basically being that gpio you could use with a scope, but today you have usb to parallel which does not serve this purpose, so only one side has gpio so that doesnt help.

Comment: @DKrueger this is not true: I can place an oscilloscope on th data+/data- of the USB cable to know what happens on the link. I already did that actually. I observed packets are sent every 1ms, which is probably due to binterval=1 in the descriptor. But the question is: does information pass on the next packet or a few packets later?

Comment: Do you need to achieve low latency in both directions - i.e. from the micro controller to the PC as well as from the PC to the micro controller? I ask because I suspect your assumption of dividing the RTT by 2 is not valid.

Comment: In my particular case, one direction might be sufficient. However I do think it is interesting for other purpose to have an idea of both directions. I was also wondering about the difference between directions. However note that I said that dividing RTT by 2 means the largest error is RTT/2. Of course with the knowledge of which direction is faster I can refine this further. Do you have more information, or cues in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For info, I just ran some tests on a Windows 10 PC fitted with two dedicated PCIe parallel port cards.

Sending TTL (square wave) pulses out using Python code (actually using Psychopy Builder and Psychopy coder) the 2 channel osciloscope showed very consistant offsets between the two pulses of 4us to 8us.

This was when the python code was run at **'above normal'** priority. 
When run at **normal priority** it was mostly the same apart from a very occassional 30us gap, presumably when task switching took place)

Comment: This doesn't measure latency like OP wanted, it measures jitter. For all I know, there could be a consistent 100ms delay for both PCIe cards and you'd get the same results. That's why OP measured round trip

Comment: You're right though in my defence I did say "for info" and I do think it's of interest for this topic. The Windows NT kernel handles the interface to the actual port. AFAIK in W10 you can't directly access things like a parallel port.

Answer (score 4):

USB Raw HID with hacked 8KHz poll rate (125us poll interval) combined with Teensy 3.2 (or above).  [Mouse overclockers](http://www.overclock.net/t/1613320/finally-i-did-it-the-8khz-polling-ultra-low-latency-mouse) have achieved 8KHz poll rate with low USB jitter, and Teensy 3.2 (Arduino clone) is able to do 8KHz poll rate with a [slightly modified USB FTDI driver](http://www.overclock.net/t/1589644/usb-mouse-hard-overclocking-2000-hz) on the PC side.

Barring this, and you need even better, you're now looking at PCI-Express parallel ports, to do lower-latency signalling via digital pins directly to pins on the parallel port. They must be true parallel ports, and not through a USB layer.  DOS apps on gigahertz-level PCs were tested to get sub-1us ability (1.4Ghz Pentium IV) with parallel port pin signalling, but if you write a virtual device driver, you can probably get sub-100us within Windows.

Use raised priority & critical sections out of the wazoo, preferably a non-garbage-collected language, minimum background apps, and essentially consume 100% of a CPU core on your critical loop, and you can definitely reliably achieve <100us.  Not 100% of the time, but certainly in the territory of five-nines (and probably even far better than that).  If you can tolerate such aberrations.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, there are two low latency methods:

1. Serial or parallel port. It is possible to get latency down to the millisecond scale, although your performance may vary depending on manufacturer. One good brand is Brainboxes, although their cards can cost over $100!
2. Write your own driver. It should be possible to achieve latencies on the order of a few hundred micro seconds, although obviously the kernel can  interrupt your process mid-way if it needs to serve something with a higher priority. This how a lot of scientific equipment actually works. (and a lot of the people telling you that a PC can't be made to work on short deadlines are wrong).

Comment: Write my own driver for what? USB? We used raw HID on USB in the project because it is available on almost any platform without hardware modification. We get something around the millisecond. We wish we had something smaller, but this is fine. What do you mean by scientific equipment? We do have “scientific equipment” (we are a lab). Especially force feedback devices. Usually they use Parallel ports (disappearing) Firewire (rare) or ethernet.

Comment: The physical interface isn't relevant. Any of these can be triggered quickly. But you will most likely need to write your own driver. Alternatively, I believe commercial offerings exist from Jungo Connectivity.

Comment: By scientific equipment, I mean that I know of several hardware devices that are operating at within timing windows that a few posts (here and elsewhere) claim are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In short, PCs aren't set up to handle that short of deadline.   Even using a bare metal RTOS on an Intel Core series processor you end up with interrupt latency (how fast the processor can respond to interrupts) in the 2-3 µS range.   (see http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/industrial-solutions-real-time-performance-white-paper.pdf)

That's ignoring any sort of communication link like USB or ethernet (or other) that requires packetizing data, handshaking, buffering to avoid data loss, etc.

USB stacks are going to have latency, regardless of how fast the link is, because of buffering to avoid data loss.  Same with ethernet.  Really, any modern stack driver on a full blown OS isn't going to be capable of low latency because of what else is going on in the system and the need for robustness in the protocols.

If you have deadlines that are in the single digit of microseconds (or even in the millisecond range), you really need to do your real time processing on a microcontroller and have the slower control loop/visualization be handled by the host.

Comment: This is an interesting point. However I can afford tens of microseconds. The question is more about identifying the communication channel with the lowest latency possible, and have an estimation of this latency. In my context I need this to measure latency of systems which have a latency over tens of milliseconds. For this measurement I need this fast communication, and make sure its part of latency can be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

You have no guarantees about latency **to [userland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space)** without [real time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). You're at the mercy of the kernel and it's [slice time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice) and preemption rules. Which could be higher than your maximum 100us.

In order for a workstation to respond to a hardware event you have to use interrupts and a device driver.
Your options are limited to interfaces that offer an [IRQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_(PC_architecture)):

- Hardware serial/parallel port.
- PCI
- Some interface bridge on PCI.

Or. If you're into abusing IO, the soundcard.

USB is not one of them, it has a 1kHz polling rate. 
Maybe Thunderbolt does, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score -1):

**Ethernet**

Look for a board that has a gigabit ethernet port directly connected to the microcontroller, and connect it to the PC directly with a crossover cable.

Comment: Don't confuse speed or bandwidth with latency. The OP is talking about _microseconds_. In _microseconds_, you can easily toggle some gpio, less easily you can make a ethernet controller send a packet.

Comment: Ethernet is an option, if I can communicate at the lowest possible level. I can try with UDP. However @linuxfan is right, this is not about bandwidth, but latency.

Comment: @Tom: the lowest possible level is to throw out the OS, and talk to the network card. Is it what you want? Otherwise, you should try bypassing the IP layer, using raw sockets with MAC address instead of UDP, thus avoiding ARP lookup.

Comment: @Tom consider to split the communication in two. One channel carries the needed data, the other (a gpio, the CTS signal of a serial interface, whatever) is the low-latency signal which only generates a timestamp and can even precede the data it refers to.

Comment: @linuxfan: I believe it's the communication form with the lowest latency, that can be reasonably expected to work on any PC. No one had a better _working_ idea yet.

Comment: I have to try bypassing the IP layer. Any advice on this point?